# Android query(Aquery) image download

Tags: android

Images downloaded from my phone can not be found in the gallery.

But downloading was successful.

It seems not to recognize the image .

```
String url = "imageURL";        
File ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File target = new File(ext, "/photo.jpg");        

aq.progress(dialog).download(url, target, new AjaxCallback<File>(){

public void callback(String url, File file, AjaxStatus status) {

if(file != null){

}else{

}

});
}
```